# Do SAS Plus passengers have lounge access at Keflavik airport?

Tags: iceland, lounges, kef, sas

I'll be traveling with [SAS Plus](https://www.flysas.com/en/sas-global/go-plus/nordic-europe/) from [Keflavik, Iceland](http://www.kefairport.is/english/) to [Oslo, Norway](https://avinor.no/en/airport/oslo-airport/).

Will I have access to any lounge at Keflavik airport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was in KEF today Nov 6 2017. SAS Plus (or any SAS) does not have access to Saga Lounge in KEF.

Comment: Yes, it does answer the question, for one lounge.

Comment: This is due to cutbacks from SAS (which almost went bancrupt) and applies to more airports than KEF.

Answer (score 4):

The [SAS Plus page you linked](https://www.flysas.com/en/travel-info/onboard/travel-classes/), does mention the access to lounges. However it does also note that this access is subject to availability.

The only lounge at Keflavik seems to be the [Saga Lounge by Iceland Air](http://www.icelandair.us/information/at-the-airport/saga-lounge/). In [its access rules](https://pixels.icelandair.com/blt61bc982c8c49f946.pdf), Iceland Air does not mention SAS passengers at all, regardless of flight class. Hence, **SAS Plus passengers do not have access to the Saga Lounge at Keflavik**. For more information on the SAS partner lounges, see [the dedicated webpage by SAS](https://www.flysas.com/en/travel-info/at-the-airport/lounges/).